# how to hide scrollbar in HorizontalScrollView in android studio

Tags: android

In one scenario I have created linear layout inside `HorizontalScrollView`  And problem is I am not able to disable its scroll bar I'v tried `scrollbarstyle` ; `scrollbarsize`, `setHorizontalScrollbarEnabled` but none of these method worked?

my xml code is :-

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontal_times"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider_one"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_times"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="16dp" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>`
```

Comment: then why are you using `HorizontalScrollView`

Comment: do u want to disable the scrollbar? or the scrolling?

Comment: I want to disable scrollbar only not scrolling @rafsanahmad007

Comment: just add `android:scrollbars="none" `in `HorizontalScrollView`

Comment: not working @RajeshKushvaha

Comment: for horizontal scrolling @Amy

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apply this property to scrollView in xml file.

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

The following will remove the scrollbar in your scrollview programmatically:

```
HorizontalScrollView horizontalScrollView = (HorizontalScrollView)
                               findViewById(R.id.horizontalScrollView);

horizontalScrollView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: @sanket the same solution was already provided earlier!!! but now it works for u !

Answer (score 0):

This attribute `android:scrollbars` can be used to remove scrollbars

Use the below code for reference

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontal_times"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/divider_one"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_times"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="16dp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this in your onCreate():

```
 HorizontalScrollView sView = (HorizontalScrollView)findViewById(R.id.horizontal_times);
// Hide the Scollbar
sView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
sView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: i'v tried that one also but not working , it shows grey color default scrollbar

Comment: try adding `android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@null"`

`android:scrollbarThumbHorizontal="@null"` in your xml.. also clean build the apk

Answer (score -1):

```
create a custom java files
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private boolean enableScrolling = true;

    public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
        return enableScrolling;
    }

    public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
        this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
       if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
       } else {
           return false;
       }
}
}
in your xml file update the following
<com.example.demo.CustomScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.example.demo.CustomScrollView>
in your activity highlight the following
CustomScrollView myScrollView = (CustomScrollView) findViewById(R.id.myScroll);
        myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(false); // disable scrolling
        myScrollView.setEnableScrolling(true); // enable scrolling
```

Comment: no need to re-invent the wheel... we already have the option to do that just use
android:scrollbars="none"